# Methods on how to extract distinct last touch values on day to day basis

Tags: mysql, sql

A quick overview; imagine a scenario wherein only 1 ID (lets call it 123) should only trigger 1 event (lets call it AAA), but due to the nature of the application, ID 123 has triggered event AAA once across 5 days, realistically 1 ID should only have 1 event trigger (there are various scenarios for why this doesn't happen). So pretty much, the whole idea here is to get what we call the last touch, meaning to say that in the 5 days that event AAA is triggered by ID 123 (day to day), the confirmed trigger of this should only be on day 5, and I would like to eliminate the count of ID 123 in day 1,2,3 & 4.

To give a better picture of things;

Example data

```
Date        ID      Event
=========================
01-09-2018  123     AAA
01-09-2018  456     AAA
02-09-2018  123     AAA
03-09-2018  123     AAA
04-09-2018  123     AAA
05-09-2018  123     AAA
```

Current output

```
Date        Count
=================
01-09-2018   2
02-09-2018   1
03-09-2018   1
04-09-2018   1
05-09-2018   1
```

Desired output

```
Date         Count
==================
01-09-2018   1
02-09-2018   0
03-09-2018   0
04-09-2018   0
05-09-2018   1
```

My query:

```
SELECT
  date,
  COUNT(DISTINCT id)
FROM
  [data]
WHERE
  event = 'AAA'
  AND date >= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 5 DAY)
GROUP BY
  date
```

Very basic query, as currently, what I'm doing is that I'm pulling data, using above query, and I'm also pulling the entire database and manually processing it using a lil elbow grease in excel. If I can build a query that achieves above desired output, would be so grateful. (Eases the pain as I automate these using Supemetrics on a daily basis). Would appreciate ideas on how to achieve this (links to tutorials/methods, pointer, anything). Many thanks!

Comment: Most people here want sample data as formatted text, not images (or links to images.)

Comment: Where is the `event` column?

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, i have made the edits.

Answer (score 0):

Please run this query. To test more, we need more schema definition and data.

```
SELECT
  date,
  COUNT(DISTINCT id)
FROM
  [data]
INNER JOIN 
(
SELECT
  event AS event1,
  MAX(date) date1,
FROM [data]
WHERE date >= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 5 DAY)
GROUP BY event  
)T
    ON [data].event= T.event1   
    AND [data].date= T.date1
WHERE
  event = 'AAA'
  AND date >= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 5 DAY)
GROUP BY
  date
```

Comment: Many thanks on your feedback, has given me an idea on how I can achieve my objective using View creation and ID IN(.....). Truly appreciate you taking the time :)